# Linq-to-sql scalar stored procedure, most direct way to get single result?

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am using the following method and looking for input on better methods or more direct methods (less code, clearer purpose):

```
_dc.StoreProcedureName().ToList().First()
```